# Warning(15,5) Kotlin: Parameter 'args' is never used

Tags: kotlin, program-entry-point

```
//This is simple Hello world example in Kotlin (using intellij IDEA)
class Main {
    fun main (args: Array<String>){
        println("sss")
    }
}
```

I expect to print the msg , instead getting the warning

> Warning:(5, 15) Kotlin: Parameter 'args' is never used

Comment: It's just a warning which appears when you define a method's parameters that you don't call anywhere in the method's body. Warnings don't fail a compilation process, errors do. Your program should run as expected. By the way in Kotlin you can write the `main()` function without any parameters, so if you remove `args: Array<String>` from the function signature, you will get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 6):

From Kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/hello-world.html).

> ...function called main with one argument called args of the type "array of strings". args will contain the command-line arguments that the program is invoked with...

Also

> it can be omitted if your program does not need to accept command-line arguments and you are using Kotlin 1.3:

```
fun main() {
println("Hello World!")
}
```

TLDR; If you don't use command-line and your Kotlin version is >= 1.3, you can remove `args`

Answer (score 3):

You can safely remove `args: Array<String>` if you won't use it. The compiler just warns you that you have unused things. You can even remove the outer `Main` class. It's not necessary in Kotlin.

```
fun main() {
    println("sss")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is a result of the unused parameter. You can remove the parameter. See [the Kotlin hello world page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/hello-world.html). You don’t even need the class to wrap the main method.

Then your code would look like:

```
fun main() {
    println("sss")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you declared `main` function as an instance method of the class `Main`.

In Kotlin an entry-point `main` function can be declared either on top-level (i.e. not in any class, just in a package)

```
package samplePackage // optional package name

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
}
```

or in an object or companion object:

```
object Main {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    }
}
```